# prepare all the posts for the loop in Google blogger template?

Tags: xml, blogger

i was reading the blogger help article ([Layout data tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en)) and figured out that the `<data.posts/>` would have all  the posts.

But from the template this shows nothing, also an error `TEMPLATE ERROR: No dictionary named: '' in: ['blog', 'skin', 'view']`

So here is my question, how can i run a loop of all the recent posts  from the template?

here is what i have did:

```
<b:loop var='thisPost' values='data:posts'>
  <h2>
    %3Ca%20href%3D%22<data:thisPost.url/>%22%3E<data:thisPost.title/>%3C%2Fa%3E
  </h2>
</b:loop>
```

and it isn't working! any idea?

**UPDATE:**

In a widget the loop is not working! here is my code:

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
        <b:includable id='allposts' var='i'>
          <b:loop var='thisPost' values='data:posts'>
            <h2>
              <a expr:href='data:thisPost.url'><data:thisPost.title/></a>
            </h2>
          </b:loop>
        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you placed this code/loop?

it won't work unless its inside `section: main` and `widget: Blog1`

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
        <b:includable id='...' var='...'>

            // it will only work inside here

        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

**UPDATE**

Blogger outputs whats inside `<b:includable id='main'>` in any widget. You can add as many `<b:includable id='...'>` beside `<b:includable id='main'>`.  If you don't link them to `<b:includable id='main'>` directly or indirectly using `<b:include name="...">` they wont execute. Here **name** inside `include` is equal to **id** inside `includable`.

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>

        <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
           <b:include name='allposts'/>
        </b:includable>

        <b:includable id='allposts'> <!-- you can remove var="i" -->
            <b:loop var='thisPost' values='data:posts'>
                <h2>
                    <a expr:href='data:thisPost.url'><data:thisPost.title/></a>
                </h2>
            </b:loop>
        </b:includable>

    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Comment: @rakibtg i have updated my answer as well, your code is fine, all you have to do is to include it inside `<b:includable id="main">` as explained in answer